# Open a file located in google file stream drive from command promt on windows

Tags: python-3.x, windows, cmd, google-drive-api

I'm currently running the scrip located on Google Drive file stream from the Spyder IDE with no problem, but looking for a run from anaconda promt. When I try:

```
cd  G:\My Drive\LBTC API\V0.2
```

It doesn't do anything at all, I got the same result if I try:

```
cd  G:\
```

Thanks

Comment: Try [`cd`](https://ss64.com/nt/cd.html)`/D "G:\My Drive\LBTC API\V0.2"`...

Comment: This solution! Works! Thanks!

Comment: Out of curiosity.. Why you post it like a comment and not as an answer?

Comment: Because just a line of code without any explanation does not appear to be enough for an answer for me; but I will write one...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The [`cd` command](https://ss64.com/nt/cd.html) (or `chdir`) changes the current directory of the given drive, but does not change the current drive:

```cmd
rem /* This changes the current directory of drive `G:` to `\My Drive\LBTC API\V0.2`,
rem    but if you are on another drive, say `C:`, you will not notice a change: */
cd "G:\My Drive\LBTC API\V0.2"
rem // When you change to the drive `G:` you will see the effect of the `cd` command:
G:
```

To change the drive as well as you must specify the `/D` option:

```cmd
rem // This changes to the drive `G:` and changes its current directory:
cd /D "G:\My Drive\LBTC API\V0.2"
```

Actually the quotation marks around the path is not needed for the `cd` command, but I tend to use them also here as they do not harm, and they are needed for paths in many other situations.

Answer (score 1):

First you change to the virtual drive and then you change the directory:

```
$ G:
$ cd /My Drive/LBTC API/V0.2
```

That should work fine, hope it helps

Comment: Well, this doesn't look like windows console commands…

Comment: It still works on Windows command line terminal